# Set image to hover by SortOrder ID

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I currently have a extension that sets a hover on an image when ever it finds a label that is called 'hover'. I wish to change this to hover an image if there is an image with sort order id which is '2'. But I do not know how to do this. The code is below.

```
    $html = "";
    $imgcount = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->count();
    if ($imgcount>0):
        $_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') -> load($_product -> getId()) -> getMediaGalleryImages();
        foreach ($_gallery as $_image ):
            if ($_image->getLabel() == 'hover'):
                $html = '<span class="hover-image"><img ' . $this->getImgSources($_product, $imgType, $w, $h, $_image -> getFile()) . ' alt="" /></span>';
            break;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $html;
```

I was hoping it would be as simple as `if ($_image->getSortOrder() == 2):` but that was just flawed thinking. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this from media.phtml?

Comment: Try getDefaultPosition() Instead of sortorder()

Comment: It's for images.php and I will give default position a shot thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$_image->getPositionDefault()`

```
print_r($_image->getData())

Array
(
    [value_id] =&gt; 2
    [file] => /l/a/label.jpg
    [label] => Label
    [position] => 0
    [disabled] => 0
    [label_default] => Label
    [position_default] => 0
    [disabled_default] => 0
    [url] => http://www.site.com/media/catalog/product/l/a/label.jpg
    [id] => 2
    [path] => /var/www/site/media/catalog/product/l/a/label.jpg
)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. That worked on a test image, but I accidently came across getPosition and it works wonders without me having to change much.

Answer (score 1):

R.S' answer works but I came across a simpler way for me to do it. 
I simple changed.

```
if ($_image->getLabel() == 'hover'):
```

to

```
if ($_image->getPosition() == 2):
```

Thanks for your help folks, wouldn't of came across this otherwise. 
I know it looks stupid, but in a panic I missed the most obvious thing in the world and that was the fix.